# What's the cmake generator for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation, updates

With Visual Studio 2017, I used the generator `"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` for `cmake`. After updating to Visual Studio 2019, what's the new corresponding generator?

Comment: `Visual Studio 16 2019` but you need to use the -A option to specify the architecture (default is 64 bit). And you need CMake-3.14 https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

from your directory where the cmakelist.txt exists. here are steps:

1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. depending upon the architecture you're using

```
    cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ../"
```

other options are:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A ARM
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A ARM64
```

it will generate makefiles required and serves your purpose

furthermore, you could

```
devenv <nameof solutions file> /build <Debug/Release option>
```

for building your project

Comment: which is the oldest cmake version supporting this?

Comment: cmake 2.8 should be minimally required

Comment: VS2019 didn't even exist when CMake 2.8 was released.